# pandas groupby : count record number with certain conditions

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following code:

```
df_user_data = df.groupby(['user_name']) \
                 .apply(lambda x: pd.Series( \
                {'user_mean_amount': sum(x['user_amount'])/len(x), \
                 'user_game_count':len(x), \
                 'user_win_count':len(x['result'] == 'Won') \
                })).reset_index()
```

The field `user_game_count` computes the total records of the given user, `user_win_count` computes the number of records whose `result == 'Won'`. However, these two fields output the same values. What did I do wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need change:

```
'user_win_count':len(x['result'] == 'Won')
```

to:

```
'user_win_count':(x['result'] == 'Won').sum()
```

for count only `True`s values. If use `len` it return length of `df`, so get same output.

---

Also

```
sum(x['user_amount'])/len(x)
```

should be simplify by:

```
x['user_amount'].mean()
```